# Access another models attributes through has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to be able to call the values from another table this way in the view.

```
<%= @team.r1.players.full_name %>
<%= @team.r2.players.full_name %>
...
<%= @team.r2.players.full_name %>
```

`r1` to `r10` are columns that hold player IDs.

The models are pretty simple and look like this.

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :players
end
```

The error that results is undefined method `players' for 3:Integer. I've attempted trying singular and plural versions to pull it but same error occurs. Looks like you might be able to do a join table but that wouldn't be ideal or doing a has_many :through association.

Schema

```
  create_table "players", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "full_name"
  end

  create_table "team_players", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.string "team_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "r1"
    t.integer "r2"
    t.integer "r3"
    t.integer "r4"
    t.integer "r5"
    t.integer "r6"
    t.integer "r7"
    t.integer "r8"
    t.integer "r9"
    t.integer "r10"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_teams_on_user_id"
  end
```

And I set up updating/adding players on a team this way.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:r1, Player.all, :id, :full_name , {required: true, include_blank: false}, {class: 'uk-input'}) %>
```

Comment: This r1, r2 to hold player ids seems weird to me but you should be able to do @team.players.find(@team.r1)

Comment: I should have been more clear. r1 to r10 is basically setting a lineup. Think of it as a roster. I did try your method and thought it should work. PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column players.team_id does not exist

Answer (score 1):

As ConorB said in comments, the `r1`, `r2`, etc. bit seems weird. If you want to limit the number of players on a team, I would suggest you do that in code, not in your data structures.

As a note: In your `Team` model you say:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :players
end
```

According to the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association):

> A has_many association indicates a one-to-many connection with another model.

This is not your case. You have a many-to-many cardinality between `Team` and `Player`. So, using `has_many` without `through` is a mistake in your case.

What you should have is:

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_players
  has_many :teams, through: :team_players
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_players
  has_many :players, through: :team_players
end

class TeamPlayer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :player
end
```

And then do:

```
<% @team.players.each do |player| %>
  <%= player.full_name %> 
<% end %>
```

You *could* decide to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`, in which case you would need a `teams_players` table, but no `TeamPlayer` model. (Personally, I *never* use HABTM, but that's a purely personal preference.) See the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) for more information.

Comment: Updated with schema for more clarity. It also shows how I set players to the roster. Let me know if you need any parts of the controller as by adding the additional model caused some issues. I'm not married to the setup but I do the r1...r10 because I'm going to do calculations based on that (different calculation for each r).

Comment: `team_players` doesn't have any `id` fields for `Team` and/or `Player`.

Comment: What about skipping the additional model and table and throwing them all into an array [0..9] and then call the index? I'm letting users set their players in the order they prefer. Then depending on that order run calculation and compare results.

Comment: Sure, you could use an array. That sounds a little awful to me, but you could do it. If I were you, I'd put an `order` column (or something similar) on `TeamPlayers` and use `has_many through` as I originally suggested.